# How to draw Kobon triangles

Tags: computational-geometry

I would like to know if *Mathematica* is capable of constructing Kobon triangles; that is, a figure consisting of the largest number of non-overlapping triangles that can be constructed using $n$ lines, $n\geq3$. It has been established that such a figure consisting of $n$ lines and $K(n)$ triangles would have an upper bound formula $K(n) \leq \lfloor n(n-2)/3 \rfloor$. Is there some special function for drawing Kobon triangles in *Mathematica*?

Reference: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KobonTriangle.html

To clarify, I am not asking the optimal solution, I just want some initial code that draw random lines, make some intersections and color some triangles formed by this lines.  But the triangles should be Kobon triangles, by which I mean only the non-overlapping triangles can be considered.

Comment: The general problem [seems open](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KobonTriangle.html) Voting to close

Comment: Wasn't intended as a joke ...

Comment: Although [Wolfram MathWorld discusses Kobon triangles](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KobonTriangle.html), I am not aware of any special function in Mathematics for generating them.

Comment: In any event, the OP might be interested in seeing the *Mathematica* notebook in the MathWorld article.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't know that is an off-topic. Anyway, thank you for the answers.

Comment: @belisariusisforth That could also have been an answer instead of closing.

Comment: There are things one can do, see e.g. the paper and MATLAB code here: http://www.johannesbader.ch/2013/09/341-triangles-with-33-lines/  I am not comfortable with this being closed.  Voting to reopen in hope of seeing some interesting, if incomplete, answers.  In the least the question can be relaxed a bit and not ask for a a fully general solution.

Comment: @Szabolcs If someone asks for the closed form of the Collatz sequence I would gladly vote to close too. But perhaps this could be discussed on meta.

Comment: @IrisLinck should clarify the question, but I didn't read this as "given $n$, any $n$, what's the optimal arrangement?".  There's some wiggle room here.  Something that works for small $n$ may be useful. Something that gives an approximate solution may be useful.

Comment: I think the question should be regarded as asking for a way to draw Kobon triangles for integers $3,\, 4,\, \dots , \,n$, but where $n$ is not an arbitrary integer.

Comment: Mr  Szabolcs got my idea. I am not asking the optimal solution, I just wanted some initial code that draw random lines, make some intersections and color some triangles formed by this lines, but the triangles should be Kombo triangles, I mean, only the non-overlapping triangles can be considered  when the code tries to identify the triangles formed by the n lines. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I enjoyed working on this, I learned how to construct a `MeshRegion` from a set of points, and to find polygons by using `FindCycle`.  First I will give the code and then explain,

```
kobonTriangle[k_] := 
  Module[{r0, r1, r2, pts, ilns, lines, edges, vertices, triangles},
   r0 := RandomReal[{-1, 1}];
   r1 := RandomReal[{-1, 0}];
   r2 := RandomReal[{0, 1}];
   pts = Transpose[
     {Array[{r0, r1} &, k - 1],
      Array[{r0, r2} &, k - 1]
      }];
   ilns = InfiniteLine /@ pts~Join~{{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}};
   lines = Flatten[
     Partition[Sort@#, 2, 1] & /@ Table[
       Flatten[List @@@ (RegionIntersection[
             ilns[[n]], #] & /@ Delete[ilns, n]), 1],
       {n, Length@ilns}], 1];

   vertices = Flatten[lines, 1] // DeleteDuplicates;
   edges = lines /. MapIndexed[#1 -> First@#2 &, vertices];
   triangles = FindCycle[Graph[#1 \[UndirectedEdge] #2 & @@@ edges], {3}, All];

   Labeled[
    MeshRegion[
     vertices, {Line /@ edges, 
      triangles /. {a_ \[UndirectedEdge] b_, b_ \[UndirectedEdge] c_, c_ \[UndirectedEdge] a_} :> 
        Polygon[{a, b, c, a}]}], 
    Row[{"Number of lines = ", k, ", Number of Triangles = ", 
      Length@triangles}]]
   ];
```

Here is are a couple of examples,

```
{kobonTriangle[5], kobonTriangle[8]}
```

[image]

In any iteration, chances are you won't find the optimal solution.  For example, for 5 and 8 lines, there are solutions with 5 and 15 triangles, respectively, rather than the 3 and 9.  But if you run the code enough times, you can often find a near-optimal solution.  I'm not claiming that it could find the actual optimal solution, I don't know enough about computational geometry to say that.  But I let it run for an hour and got these results:

[image]

### How it works

I was inspired by Trevor Simonton's javascript code [here](http://www.trevorsimonton.com/jekyll/projects/kobon-triangles/).  The idea is to generate `k` random lines that intersect so as to get a decent number of triangles.  To that end, we start with one line that is oriented horizontally, and then generate `k-1` lines that cross this line.

Here is the code to do this,

```
r0 := RandomReal[{-1, 1}];
r1 := RandomReal[{-1, 0}];
r2 := RandomReal[{0, 1}];
pts = Transpose[
  {Array[{r0, r1} &, k - 1],
   Array[{r0, r2} &, k - 1]
   }];
ilns = InfiniteLine /@ pts~Join~{{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}};
```

You can see the lines via,

```
Graphics[ilns]
```

[image]

We need to zoom out to see all the intersections

```
Graphics[ilns, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2.0}, {-2, 2.0}}]
```

[image]

Now I would like to cut off the lines after the intersection points to create a closed shape.  First I will use `RegionIntersection` to find all the intersection points.  Then I create line segments between each intersection point, but first I sort the intersection points to make sure that we don't have any overlapping line segments.

```
lines = Flatten[
   Partition[Sort@#, 2, 1] & /@ Table[
     Flatten[List @@@ (RegionIntersection[
           ilns[[n]], #] & /@ Delete[ilns, n]), 1],
     {n, Length@ilns}], 1];
vertices = Flatten[lines, 1] // DeleteDuplicates;
Graphics[{Line /@ lines, {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point /@ vertices}}]
```

[image]

So we have our basic shape, but how to find the triangles, and only the non-overlapping triangles?  By making a `Graph` that is isomorphic to the shape above, we can take advantage of the `Graph` functions in *Mathematica*

```
edges = lines /. MapIndexed[#1 -> First@#2 &, ipts]
Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
(* {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {5, 3}, {3, 6}, {6, 7}, {8, 9}, {9,
   5}, {5, 4}, {9, 10}, {10, 1}, {1, 7}, {8, 10}, {10, 2}, {2, 6}} *)
```

[image]

Now we can find the triangles easily enough, and only non-overlapping triangles will be found because we've cut the lines into non-overlapping segments already.

```
triangles = FindCycle[Graph[#1 \[UndirectedEdge] #2 & @@@ edges], {3}, All]
Length@triangles
(* {{8 \[UndirectedEdge] 9, 9 \[UndirectedEdge] 10, 10 \[UndirectedEdge] 8}, {2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 
  6 \[UndirectedEdge] 2}, {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 10, 10 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}, {3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 3}} *)
(* 4 *)
```

Now we just wrap it all up into a `MeshRegion` for display purposes,

```
Labeled[
 MeshRegion[
  vertices, {Line /@ edges, 
   triangles /. {a_ \[UndirectedEdge] b_, b_ \[UndirectedEdge] c_, c_ \[UndirectedEdge] a_} :> 
     Polygon[{a, b, c, a}]}], 
 Row[{"Number of lines = ", k, ", Number of Triangles = ", 
   Length@triangles}]]
```

[image]

So this code is perhaps not efficient - I imagine that `FindCycles` and the routine to find the intersection both scale at or worse than $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ but $n$ is small so that is no worry.

### One slight problem

For every time we get a decent shape like

```
kobonTriangle[14]
```

[image]

we will get 5 that look like this,

[image]

where some of the lines are so long as to make the shape hard to view.  I'm not sure how to discriminate against these shapes, though they are valid shapes, and the number of triangles is counted correctly.