# How to find non-overlapping triangles?

Tags: graphics, regions, computational-geometry, geometry, trigonometry

There are at least a few non-overlapping triangles made by the lines in the following graphic, how would I isolate them?

```
pts = RandomReal[1, {7, 2, 2}];
g = Graphics[{InfiniteLine @@@ pts}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1, 3}}]
```

[image]

**Update:**

Jason B gave a nice answer, but it needs it to work with both `Line[]` and `InfiniteLine[]`, for which the `triangles[]` function below doesn't work:

```
SeedRandom[4430];
pts = RandomReal[1, {3, 2, 2}];
l = InfiniteLine @@@ pts; h = 
 Line@{{{0, 0}, {0, 2}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {1, 2}}};
lines = Join[l, {h}];
g = Graphics[{lines, LightBlue, Triangle /@ triangles[lines]}, 
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Suggestion:  1) Find the set ${\cal P}$ of all intersection points by finding intersections of all pairs of lines, 2) find the set ${\cal S}$ of all potential triangles by taking all triplets of such points in ${\cal P}$ where each pair lie on the same line, 3) delete from ${\cal S}$ all triangles that contain another point from ${\cal P}$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97732/9490

Answer (score 3):

Borrowing from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110383/9490),

```
triangles[lines:{__InfiniteLine}]:= Module[
    {lineSegments,vertices,edges,triangles},
    lineSegments = Flatten[
        Map[Function @ Partition[Sort @ #, 2, 1],
            Table[
                Flatten[
                    List@@@Map[RegionIntersection[Part[lines, n], #]&, Delete[lines, n]],
                    1
                ],
                {n, Length @ lines}
            ]
        ],
        1
    ]; 

   vertices = Flatten[lineSegments, 1] // DeleteDuplicates;
   edges = lineSegments /. MapIndexed[#1 -> First@#2 &, vertices];
   triangles = FindCycle[Graph[#1 \[UndirectedEdge] #2 & @@@ edges], {3}, All];
   triangles = triangles[[All,All,1]];
   vertices[[#]]&/@triangles
]
```

Plotting directly as

```
SeedRandom[4430];
pts = RandomReal[1, {7, 2, 2}];
lines = InfiniteLine @@@ pts;
g = Graphics[{lines, LightBlue, Triangle /@ triangles[lines]}, 
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, nice answer. But what if I had lines as well? like this `l = InfiniteLine @@@ pts; h = Line @ {{{0, 0}, {0, 2}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {1, 2}}}; lines = Join[l, {h}]`

Comment: It should be fairly straightforward to modify this to account for line segments, the post I link to above should help with that, as it explains all the bits of code used here.