# Automated searching for maximal 2D point configurations

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, geometry, maximum

I have some black-box function that takes lists of 2D points, and I would like to find some practical methods of searching for collections of points that maximize it.

**Motivation**

I've come across the need to search for sets of points in the plane that satisfy/optimize constraints so many times, but have never adequately found workable strategies in Mathematica. To name a few of these times:

- When packing geometric entities in various ways
- Searching for graph embeddings with certain properties
- Various combinatorial optimization problems

**Minimal Example**

[Kobon triangles](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KobonTriangle.html) (mentioned in comments), is a nice example of this type of problem: *searching for arrangements of lines that make the most triangles*. Jason B. provided a [brute-force solution to this problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97732/how-to-draw-kobon-triangles) by converting the lines to a graph, which is great, but to illustrate my question let's look at it this way: consider the following function `f` that takes (flattened) lines as arguments

```
(* the ith line is `InfiniteLine[{{xi1, yi1}, {xi1, yi2}}] *)
f[x11, y11, x12, y12, x21, y21, x22, y22, ...] := ...
```

and returns the number of non-overlapping triangles. Here are some inputs `pts` where `f` is 1:

```
SeedRandom[4430];
pts = RandomReal[1, {3, 2, 2}];
lines = RegionIntersection[#, Disk[{0, 0}, 10]] & /@ (InfiniteLine /@ pts);
tri = triangles[lines];
Graphics[{lines, LightBlue, Triangle /@ tri}, Frame -> False, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

**Where I get stuck**

I first tried using `FindMaximum` on the simplest case of only 3 lines (i.e. find 1 triangle from 12 coordinates). As you can see below, it fails to find a set of 6 points in the plane, *even when supplied with the correct coordinates as starting values* (which was very strange to me):

```
d = Disk[{0, 0}, 20];
s = FindMaximum[{f[x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, x5, y5, x6, 
    y6], {x1, y1} \[Element] d && {x2, y2} \[Element] 
     d && {x3, y3} \[Element] d && {x4, y4} \[Element] 
     d && {x5, y5} \[Element] d && {x6, y6} \[Element] d}, 
    {{x1, 0.7242101930120808`}, {y1, 0.029677803428552307`}, {x2, 0.00816459598186059`}, {y2, 0.47699819634429996`}, {x3, 0.06540238199229464`}, {y3, 0.69214964488526`}, {x4,0.6253484480271967`}, {y4, 0.9545360094125843`}, {x5, 0.12098288193445206`}, {y5, 0.7013188710966709`}, {x6, 0.2806641729642241`}, {y6, 0.926496649677153`}}]
```

[image]

Neither `NMaximize` nor `FindInstance` seem up to the task either:

```
NMaximize[{f[x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, x5, y5, x6, 
    y6], {x1, y1} \[Element] d && {x2, y2} \[Element] 
     d && {x3, y3} \[Element] d && {x4, y4} \[Element] 
     d && {x5, y5} \[Element] d && {x6, y6} \[Element] d}, {x1, y1, 
   x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, x5, y5, x6, y6}, 
  Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
```

[image]

```
FindInstance[f[x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, x5, y5, x6, y6] == 1, {x1, y1, x2,
y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, x5, y5, x6, y6}, Reals, 1]
```

[image]

When the variables are continuous and the function you are looking to maximize is integer-valued, this is no doubt a hard problem. **However, are there are definitely better ways out there to solve this than grid/random search?**

**Code for f in the above example**

```
f[x1_, y1_, x2_, y2_, x3_, y3_, x4_, y4_, x5_, y5_, x6_, y6_] := 
 Module[{l, h, lines},
  l = InfiniteLine /@ {{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}, {{x3, y3}, {x4, 
       y4}}, {{x5, y5}, {x6, y6}} };
  lines = RegionIntersection[#, Disk[{0, 0}, 10]] & /@ l;
  Length[triangles@lines]
  ]

triangles[lines:{__}]:= Module[
    {lineSegments, vertices, edges, triangles},

    lineSegments = Flatten[
        Map[Function @ Partition[Sort @ #, 2, 1],
            Table[With[{l=
                List @@@ Map[RegionIntersection[Part[lines, n], #]&, Delete[lines, n]]},
                Flatten[Select[l, Depth[#] >= 3&], 1]
                ],
                {n, Length @ lines}
            ]
        ],
        1
    ]; 

   vertices = Flatten[lineSegments, 1] // DeleteDuplicates;
   edges = lineSegments /. MapIndexed[#1 -> First@#2 &, vertices];
   triangles = FindCycle[Graph[#1 \[UndirectedEdge] #2 & @@@ edges], {3}, All];
   triangles = triangles[[All, All, 1]];
   vertices[[#,1]] & /@ triangles
]
```

**Additional Details**

- A valid assumption is that all the points are in some `Disk[{0, 0}, n]` or another fixed region.
- Since this is useful for finding geometric configurations subject to constraints - perhaps `FindGeometricConjectures` would be a better fit to try (when v12 comes out)?

Comment: This seems familiar.  Are you trying to use `FindMaximum` to find the maximum Kobon triangles?

Comment: No just trying to see how to get Mathematica to move points around in 2d to optimize any function

Comment: It is unlikely you are going to have much luck using these methods when the function you are tackling has only integer values.

Comment: Why not just solve for the vertices and use that information to answer whatever it is that you are asking for?

Comment: In my case, there is no way to solve for the vertices and anyway I'd like a black box technique for similar problems. At the very least, optimizing an integer valued function over configurations in a region could be done better than random search with BayesianMaximize no?

Comment: So the lists can be of arbitrary length, correct? You can't just parameterize a list of 2D points length $L$ with $2L$ parameters?

Comment: No they can be assumed to be limited to N lines